How to access certs from a spring boot jar file on a server?
I have running a spring boot application as a jar file on a server (open shift).
I need different keystores and truststores depending on the environment. This means I can't commit those files but need to load them over a config map to the server. I placed the files in a seperatly created folder /etc/trusts and the application is running in the /app folder. In my configuration I address the keysore and truststore with /etc/trusts/keystore.p12 and /etc/trusts/truststore.p12 but I get the error:
"class path resource [etc/trusts/keystore.p12] cannot be opened because it does not exist"
But it exists and can see it on the server. How can I get it running so that spring boot can access the files in the /etc/trusts folder?
Info: I checked if the config has the leading slash /etc and it is correctly stored, so only the error message doesn't use it.
How I try to load the files:
val resource: Resource = resourceLoader.getResource(fileLocation)
    return resource.inputStream

For my local environment I have the files within src/main/resources and address them in the config with classpath:keystore.p12 etc. It works well.
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

can you please show the property that refers to the resource (application.properties or @Value annotation)?

It's a little bit complicated: the application.yaml contains a variable to the configs. The configs are placed in a config map on the server. Its a JSON string with an array of objects and each object has multiple attributes. One of them is "keystore": "/etc/trusts/keystore.p12".
The config is correctly loaded, I know it because there are several other steps before where the config is used and there is a check method also.

As can been seen in documentation of getResource u need to specify whether the resource is on classpath or in your case file.
So you have to prepend file: to your path e.g.:
val resource: Resource = resourceLoader.getResource(`file:/etc/trusts/keystore.p12`)

